# local variable accessed outside exception

Tags: ruby, scope

I am getting `` undefined local variable or method `page' `` which started happening when I added the timeout block:

```
begin
  Timeout::timeout(30) do
    page =  Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  Rollbar.error("Timeout on #{url}")
  return
end

# other code using page
```

Is something wrong with my Timeout code/rescue?

Comment: Could you add a bit more context? As-is, `page` will always be undefined outside the timeout block, not just when the timeout block fails to return.

Comment: Not sure what to add, I am getting `undefined local variable or method `page'` which started happening when I added the timeout block. Trying to understand why would this happen

Comment: What line is that error coming from? Where is page defined outside the timeout block? That's the context that seems to be missing. E.g. `loop { x = 1; break}; x` will throw a similar error. Is that a valid way to reduce your current problem?

Comment: @Ajedi32 yes, trying with class variable to unscope `page` from the block

Comment: "class variable" - if you mean that I think you mean, that's a whole another can of worms you don't want to open :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables defined in blocks are scoped to their respective block. For example:

```
1.times do
  some_var = 1
  p some_var # Prints 1
end

p some_var # Will throw an error
```

If you want to scope the variable to a higher context, you have to define it outside the block:

```
some_var = nil
1.times do
  some_var = 1
  p some_var # Prints 1
end

p some_var # Prints 1
```

In your case:

```
page = nil # Define the scope of the variable up here
begin
    Timeout::timeout(30) do
      page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) # Now set that variable
    end
rescue Timeout::Error
    Rollbar.error("Timeout on #{url}")
    return
end

# other code using page
```

Comment: is begin a block? can I declare it inside the begin?

Comment: @NickGinanto Begin isn't a block. At least, not in the sense I was referring to. So yes, you can define `page` there, just not inside the timeout block.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: the problem is not related to your `begin/rescue/end` block, so let's remove the exception handling for a moment:

```
Timeout::timeout(30) do
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
end

page #=> undefined local variable or method `page'
```

This happens because the `do/end` block creates a new [variable scope](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variable+Scope) and

> (...) any local variables created inside it do not leak to the surrounding scope.

You could define `page` outside (i.e. before) the block:

```
page = nil

Timeout::timeout(30) do
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
end

page #=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document...>
```

But there's another option.

If you read the documentation for [`Timeout::timeout`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html#method-c-timeout), you'll notice that it returns the block's result. So you can just write:

```
page = Timeout::timeout(30) { Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) }
```

The documentation for [`OpenURI::OpenRead#open`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open) is interesting, too. It reveals that you can pass several options to `open`, in particular:

> **`:read_timeout`**
>
> :read_timeout option specifies a timeout of read for http connections.
>
> **`:open_timeout`**
>
> :open_timeout option specifies a timeout of open for http connections.

[See [`Net::HTTP#open_timeout`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#open_timeout) and [`Net::HTTP#read_timeout`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#read_timeout) for details]

Assuming that `url` is a HTTP URL, you could replace your `timeout` call with:

```
begin
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, open_timeout: 30, read_timeout: 30))
rescue Timeout::Error
  Rollbar.error("Timeout on #{url}")
  return
end
```

Or more specific:

```
begin
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, open_timeout: 30, read_timeout: 30))
rescue Net::ReadTimeout
  Rollbar.error("Timeout reading #{url}")
  return
rescue Net::OpenTimeout
  Rollbar.error("Timeout opening #{url}")
  return
end
```

Note that `begin` does *not* create a new variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `page` is only visible whitin the `timeout` block. You could initialize `page` before the block, e.g. `page = nil` or encapsulated the retrieval of the `page` value in a method.

```
def retrieve(url2)
  Timeout::timeout(30) do
    Nokogiri::HTML(open(url2))
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  Rollbar.error("Timeout on #{url2}")

  nil
end

page = retrieve(url)
```

Comment: And only inside of that block.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so it should be a class variable?

Comment: @NickGinanto: not necessarily. Just be declared one level above.

Comment: @NickGinanto: `page = Timeout::timeout do ...` or something like this.

Comment: @NickGinanto: or even `page = begin; Timeout::timeout do ...`